# Get Highchart (/ Highstock) from public data (json)

Tags: highcharts

Here's an example how to plot the chart with json data

Is there a way to chart this from public data (meaning any listed company)? For example from bloomberg data? https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/AAPL:US

I guess the format is just wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

Answer (score 0):

For Highcharts the structure of data is important, not the source. All you should do is set the correct link and series data, but unfortunately I see a problem with CORS: [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work/10636765)

```
    series: [{
        data: data.data_values,
        ...
    }]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5u0jv31y/